# Addressing the hotfix, bugfix, and versioning aspects for GitFlow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using GitFlow to manage an application that includes 3 features and 2 releases.
Release 1.0.0 will include Feature 1, while Release 2.0.0 will include Feature 2 and Feature 3.

so here are the GitFlow steps for the release 1.0.0

1. Create the `Feature 1` branch from develop.
2. Finish `Feature 1` and merge it back into develop.
3. Ensure that `develop` is stable and ready for release.
4. Create a `release` branch (e.g., release/1.0.0) from `develop`.
5. Test on the `release` branch and fix any bugs.
6. Create a release tag (e.g., v1.0.0) on the `release` branch.
7. Publish the application to the App Store with version `1.0.0`.
8. Merge the `release` branch into both `main` and `develop`.

As the application 1.0.0 is released in the appstore and people are using it,

here is the plan for the second release 2.0.0:

1. `Features 2` and `Features 3` are finished.
2. Merge into the `develop` branch.
3. Created a `release` branch (e.g., release/2.0.0) from `develop`.
4. testing is ongoing on release/2.0.0

Releasing 1.0.0 using GitFlow looks good to me but I'm looking to address hotfixes, bugfixes, and versioning using GitFlow for the following use cases:

1. If people report a critical bug in 1.0.0 that requires the immediate release of a new application?
2. If people report a bug, I want to fix it and include that bug fix in the next release, 2.0.0 ?
3. QA reports a bugs in release/2.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Atlassian's Gitflow workflow tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) for reference, and for how to do this easily with the `gitflow` tool. For versioning, see [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/).

- Release branches are for release tasks and bugs which must be fixed in this release.
- Hotfix branches are for urgent changes to production.
- Feature branches are for everything else that can wait until the next release.

Bugs can be fixed in a feature branch, or a hotfix branch, or a release branch. Which you use depends on the urgency of the fix.

> If people report a critical bug in 1.0.0 that requires the immediate release of a new application?

Make a hotfix branch off main. Fix the bug. Merge it into both main and develop. Since it's a bugfix, increment the 3rd number; release 1.0.1.

> If people report a bug, I want to fix it and include that bug fix in the next release, 2.0.0 ?

Since you're in the middle of releasing 2.0.0 and want it in 2.0.0, fix it in the 2.0.0 release branch.

Once 2.0.0 is released the release branch will be merged back into `develop` bringing the bugfix with it.

> QA reports a bugs in release/2.0.0 ?

If you want it fixed in 2.0.0, fix it in the 2.0.0 release branch. Same as above.

If it can wait until the next release, fix it in a feature branch.

Comment: `Non-hotfix bug fixes are 'features' (I prefer 'issue'). Fix them in a feature branch.`
Does it mean creating a new branch, for example, feature/bug_fix_issue_name
and merging back to develope and release/2.0.0 ?

Comment: I have updated the third expected use case in the question.

Comment: @Shubham To clarify, these questions are while you're in the middle of releasing 2.0.0? If so, I need to adjust my answer. I answered for before the 2.0.0 release started.

Comment: Just to be clear, fixing bugs in release 2.0.0 can be done by creating a different bug fix branch off release/2.0.0, right?

Comment: @Shubham Yes, you can branch from the release branch, fix the bug, and then merge back into the 2.0.0 release branch. It's the Feature Branch Workflow, but off a release branch. Note that doing big bug fixes in a release branch may indicate the code is not ready for release.